# How to generate java classes for ORMlite from existing database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have an existing SQLite database and need to generate classes for ORMlite from this database. I could do this manually but looks like a boring and time consuming task... do you know any tools that could do it for me or at least could help me in this task?

I found a similar question about this on SO but it's a quite old one :
 [how to generate a java class code from a sqlite database for ORMLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620272/how-to-generate-a-java-class-code-from-a-sqlite-database-for-ormlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find any tools that suits my needs I just wrote a quick Python script doing the job, you can get it [here](https://github.com/livos/ormlite-java-class-generator)

Maybe it doesn't suits all needs but it suits mines so maybe it could be useful to anybody else.

Comment: Great work, only sad thing is that it supports just SQL Lite and not others DB like MySQL/Maria DB.

Comment: Thank you. Well i just did this as quickly as i could just to solve the problem I had, not really to make a great and perfect tool that always works perfectly and made to be used by others. Just shared it because i did it for me and that cost me nothing to share.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much [@Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5962961/laurent) for the Python script, I have adjusted the script a little so that it works with the mysql database. [have fun with it.](https://github.com/b166er/ormlite-java-class-generator)